# Stalks of Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am currently learning Algebraic Geometry and (at least in my very limited experience so far) stalks have proven to be very useful when discussing properties of locally ringed spaces and schemes. Manifolds can be considered as locally ringed spaces and in fact resemble schemes in some sense. Hence the question

> Of what use are stalks to the discussion of properties of (topological or smooth) manifolds?

I haven't seen any references to stalks with respect to manifolds in classical literature on algebraic topology. Neither have I seen an extensive discussion of manifolds as examples of locally ringed spaces in standard literature on algebraic geometry (note however that this might stem from the fact that I have only read a semester's worth on algebraic geometry). A shallow search on the internet did not produce more information either, so I hope asking for reference is appropriate.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might be better off looking at complex geometry (e.g. that of Riemann surfaces) instead of smooth geometry. In many references, germs of holomorphic functions (stalks of the sheaf of holomorphic functions) are used when talking about analytic continuation and related things. A rough intuition about why germs are more helpful in complex geometry is that holomorphic functions and algebraic functions are both very rigid. In nice situations the germ of a function at a point determines the function. In contrast, the germ of a smooth function at a point tells you little about the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's definitely true that smooth manifolds can be regarded as locally ringed spaces, but this is seldom the approach taken in any introduction on manifolds. It's a good question as to why this is not done. There are probably two reasons:

1. It adds complications unnecessary to the development of the material; indeed one can escape saying the word locally ringed space when discussing smooth manifolds entirely, so why add the extra terminology?
2. We actually don't need to be too concerned about local objects versus global objects when we deal with smooth manifolds, because of partitions of unity.

The first point does not need much explanation. The second point is important, though. If you read John Lee's book on Smooth Manifolds, you will notice that the tangent space is defined to be the space of pointed derivations at $p$ of $\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)$, the space of smooth functions on the manifold. That is, we define  $T_pM$ to be the set of maps $\partial:\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ that are $\mathbb{R}-$linear and satisfy the pointed Leibniz rule:
$$ \partial(fg)=g(p)\partial(f)+f(p)\partial(g).$$
This is well and good, and is a correct definition, but it does not generalize. If you look at Tu's book on the same subject, he defines $T_pM$ to be the set of pointed derivations at $p$ of the *germs of smooth functions* $\mathscr{C}^\infty_p(M)$, which is exactly the stalk of the structure sheaf at $p$. In particular, elements of $\mathscr{C}^\infty_p(M)$ are equivalence classes $\langle U,f\rangle$ so that $f$ is smooth on $U$ and $p\in U$.  The definition is the same, $\partial:\mathscr{C}^\infty_p(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ an $\mathbb{R}-$linear map satisfying the same Leibniz rule.

So, why the difference? When we pass to more algebraic objects – like complex manifolds, we start to run into issues. If we look at a compact complex manifold $X$, it follows from the theory of holomorphic functions (Liouville's Theorem) that any global holomorphic function $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is a constant. If we try the first definition of the tangent space above, we run quickly into issues. For instance, it isn't hard to see that a pointed derivation $\partial$ like above has $\partial(\lambda)=0$ for any scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. So, it we try to define $T_pX$ to be the set of pointed derivations 
$$ \partial:\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to \mathbb{C}$$
we really just get a derivation $\partial:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$. Actually, such a $\partial$ vanishes on constants, so by this definition, $T_pX=0$ no matter what compact complex manifold we choose. However, if we work instead with germs of functions, we get the right amount of functions, so that the tangent space could be defined as the set of pointed derivations 
$$ \partial:\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to \mathbb{C}.$$
The moral of this story is that in the smooth category, the difference between local and global objects is not so different as in the complex or algebraic case. So, when we study complex manifolds, algebraic varieties, or schemes we really do need to use sheaves to keep track of local data. In the smooth case, we can escape without worrying so much.

By the way, the two definitions are equivalent in the smooth manifolds case because you can choose a bump function around $p$, call it $\rho$ such that $\rho\equiv 1$ in a neighborhood of $p$, and extend germs of $f_p$ to global functions by multiplying by $\rho$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer. So stalks are indeed of use to define the right notion of tangent space, in the sense that it applies to more than the category of smooth manifolds. Just out of curiosity: Do you know of any other usage of stalks?

Comment: There are a lot of uses for stalks. For instance, a sequence of sheaves $\cdots\to \mathscr{F}_i\to \mathscr{F}_{i+1}\to \cdots$ is exact if and only if the sequence of stalk maps $\cdots\to \mathscr{F}_{i,P}\to \mathscr{F}_{i+1,P}\to \cdots$ is exact. So, a lot of sheaf theoretic things can be reduced to local calculations involving complex analysis, or commutative algebra, depending on which category you work in.

Comment: Oh sorry I was imprecise. I meant in the context of manifolds. This kind of use of stalks you mention was exactly what motivated my question...

Comment: Well, this still works. In complex manifold theory one is interested especially in coherent sheaves, and stalks are an indispensable tool. If you refer specifically to the structural sheaf, then I would say that questions of analytic continuation (as mentioned in the comment of jgon above) use stalks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am looking forward to doing some complex manifold theory then I guess :)